# How to set dynamic strings as part of an attribute of output?

Tags: typescript

```
interface Artist {
  name: string;
}

function produceForArtist<T extends Artist, P extends any, K extends string>
  (artist, produce, productionName) :
  <Artist & {[K: string]: P}>     // <-- Need to fill in here to set a dynamic key type here
{ 
  return { ...artist, [productionName]: produce }
}

produceForArtist('Da Vinci', new Song, 'songs')
produceForArtist('Da Vinci', new Movie, 'movies')
produceForArtist('George Lucas', new Movie, 'films')

// The goal is to create these but {produceForArtist} does not need to  care about how it will be used

interface Musician extends Artist {
  albums: Albums[];
}

interface Painter extends Artist {
  paintings: Painting[];
}
```

Comment: Perfect, care to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add a dynamic property, we can use an [*Intersection* type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types), having the `Artist` as base type, while joining it with a *mapped type* (combined with Generics) containing the extra property.

We can start defining this type:

```
type ArtistWithProduction<K extends string, P> = Artist & { [K1 in K]: P }
```

Where `K` is the productionName, narrowed from the generic `string` type to the exact string, while `K1 in K` simply means to map the string as an object property.

Then you can update your function in order to return this type:

```
function produceForArtist<P extends object, K extends string>
    (artist: Artist, produce: P, productionName: K):
    ArtistWithProduction<K, P>   // <-- Need to fill in here to set a dynamic key type here
{
    return { ...artist, [productionName]: produce } as ArtistWithProduction<K, P>;
}
```

Note that I added `as ArtistWithProduction<K, P>` to return type. This is necessary since TS currently has limitations, so object literals cannot inherit the correct typings by themself, even if `productionName` is typed as `K`. (see [TS #26797](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26797), [TS #21030](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21030))

You can see the typings in [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=7&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJTMAzmZBvZAXwCgEAbOLLZAZQHsQBzfI44sATwAcV1McA6sDAALAApQ6AEwCuCTAwA8AaWQQAHpBBTqOKKEYAaZGIB8yALzJiyW2gzZcAMhYBtZQEZkoZMoC6AFwmrMQwMiDywAzIXJKySABidFB8jopiapoQ2tR0AEYAVhDyxqoaWjrIegamNnYAFHAOOEGpOMax0nIQQWIdcXIKIABycAC2Pb4AlAF1tm1gQqISXZFKysZmdgD028iKALQHyMMQEFLIYHTIMMBkZN4gyCLQKFdVELhwyFIcIOPABDIADWEA4l24KBeUAgxDwc2QMLAMigTwIADpMU1+GBjK5OvEhqMJoEYgMkERkJR7DiluJyUMVJtTABuYgkUgMHA-OAANVACGAljJqwgSRSzTA9QA5AARb78iLAaXGEAQADutAYjHqU2M0qw2qw0qmbKkfIFwHRhqYWBZyCAA).

I'd like to add, I've seen you're using `[productionName]: produce` like if this is a single item, even if name is plural. If you'd like to allow an array of items, and the reason why you added `produce` is just to have the class **type**, you can change your function typings to:

```
// Replacing the single item `P` with an array of P, `P[]`
type ArtistWithProduction<K extends string, P> = 
    Artist & { [K1 in K]: P[] }

function produceForArtist<P, K extends string>
    // Using the newable signature allows you to pass the class, not an instance
    (artist: Artist, produce: { new(...args: any): P }, productionName: K):
    ArtistWithProduction<K, P>
{
    return { ...artist, [productionName]: [] } as ArtistWithProduction<K, P>;
}
```

Where `produce` is now a Class, not an Instance, i.e. `Song` instead of `new Song()`.

The you can call your function using just the class reference (`Song`).

```
const daVinci = produceForArtist('Da Vinci', Song, 'songs');
daVinci.songs;
```